# Javascript Page Scroll Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a JavaScript tabbed menu, which loads different content (text/photos) when a menu item is selected.

However, when you click a menu item, the scroll position jumps to the middle or bottom of the element (in this case the photo) where I need it to show the menu and the top of the photo.

Can someone advise how I set it up  to maintain the fixed position at the top, so that the menu and top of the photo is visible, leaving the user to scroll down manually.

https://jsfiddle.net/njd9L7ok/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastItem = null;
    $('#listingmenu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        newItem = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);
        if (newItem != lastItem) {
            $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
            // fade out all open subcontents
            $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
            // fade in new selected subcontent
            $('#' + newItem).show(600);
            lastItem = newItem;
        }
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent default behavior on the click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listingmenu').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // all your other code
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

Comment: So I just add this to the top of the js?

Comment: You need to pass the event into the function you are calling on click. I left all of your function out just to be cleaner, but I'll update it to look more like your code.

Answer (score 0):

The links point to `div`s on the page, so when clicked they will scroll to the linked `div`. Just use a property other than `href` in your logic. In this case I used a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and referenced it with [jQuery's `data` method](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastItem = null;
    $('#listingmenu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        newItem = this.getAttribute('data-pic');
        if (newItem != lastItem) {
            $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
            // fade out all open subcontents
            $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
            // fade in new selected subcontent
            $('#' + newItem).show(600);
            lastItem = newItem;
        }
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

```css
}
ul#listingmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#listingmenu li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #272e3b;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#listingmenu .current {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fe8f25;
}
ul#listingmenu li:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fe8f25;
}
ul#listingmenu li a {
    padding: 2px 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px Avenir, Arial, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #272e3b;
}
ul#listingmenu li a:hover {
    color: #fe8f25;
    border: none;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul id="listingmenu">
 <li class="current"><a href="#" data-pic="div1">MENU 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-pic="div2">MENU 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-pic="div3">MENU 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-pic="div4">MENU 4</a></li>
</ul><br><br>
<div class="pbox" id="div1"><img src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5768/21412232748_5834dc04f2_h.jpg"></div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2"><img src="//c2.staticflickr.com/6/5773/21403313739_fd703c4be9_k.jpg"></div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3"><img src="//c1.staticflickr.com/1/610/20974896524_4aa6ce41b1_h.jpg"></div>
<div class="pbox" id="div4"><img src="//c1.staticflickr.com/1/585/21416851580_6d97a4dac9_k.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use data attributes as they are excluded within HTML purifier (long story!!), so I had to use href tags as an alternative.

Comment: Using hrefs may be preferable anyway to ensure that users have useful menu items to click even when Javascript is disabled.